# bison yacc yyerror doesn't work

Tags: bison, yacc

I'm begginer to Yacc programming and I have an easy task to write a program, which checks whether an input text file
contains a sequence of correctly paired parentheses. Any incorrect sequence 
should be signaled as "Syntax error!". I use bison and flex.

Example correct data:
    (()()((())())())
but
    (()
is incorrect.

My problem is that I think it should work, but it seems like yyerror is not working. Maybe I'm doing something wrong, please correct me.
Here's my code
Yacc code:

```
 %{
int yylex();
void yyerror(char* x);
%}
%%
S: S A
 |A
 ;
A: '('S')'
  |'(' ')'
  ;
```

And the lex code:

```
%{
#include "y.tab.h"
%}
%%
[\(\)] return(yytext[0]);
. {printf("%c - error!\n",yytext[0]);}

%%
void yyerror(char* x)
{
    printf("syntax error");
    exit(1);
}
```

So the problem is that it doesn't fire a syntax error, it doesn't matter how much parentheses I write.
edit:
Here's how I compile it:
[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9hc2.png)

Comment: Don't print `"syntax error"`. Print the error you are provided with.

Comment: It is not the problem, because the exit(1) also doesn't work. It doesn't enter the yyerror method

Comment: That's why I posted it as a comment, not an answer. It remains wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide a `main()` function which (at the minimum) calls `yyparse()`. Otherwise, the `main` from `libfl` will be used. That `main` does not call `yyparse()`; rather, it repeatedly calls `yylex` until an EOF is signalled. (`libfl` is part of Flex, not bison, so it cannot rely on `yyparse` even existing.)

There is really no need to link with `-lfl`. The `main()` definition there is not useful to you and the only other thing in the library is a dummy definition of `yywrap()`. You don't define `yywrap()`, so the library function will be called; however, rather than depending on the library, you could simply add

```
%option noyywrap
```

to your flex code (just before the `%%`), and then the generated scanner will not call `yywrap()`.

There is also no need to use the `-y` flag when you invoke bison. The only reason to use `-y` is to be able to process legacy yacc files with bison. I suppose you are using the flag so that that generated parser is called `y.tab.c`; without the flag, it would be called `z5.tab.c` (and the header file will be `z5.tab.h`); you could just use those names. (Or you could tell bison the precise filename you would like it to use, by using the `-o` flag.)

Finally, two notes about your lex file:

1. The pattern for parentheses could just be written:

   ```
   [()]  { return yytext[0]; }
   ```

   There is no need to backslash-escape parentheses inside a character class, because no characters other than `]`, `-` and `\` have special meaning inside a character class.
2. The pattern `.` does not match a newline character, which is why the newline characters in your input are not producing error messages. In fact, none of your patterns match the newline character, so when you type a newline, the default rule is invoked. The default rule is equivalent to `ECHO`, which bison defines to be something like:

   ```
   fputs(yytext, yyout);
   ```

   (or `fprintf(yyout, "%s", yytext);`)

   That's why an extra newline is output when you type a newline.

Comment: I followed your advice and now I get the: undefined reference '@winmain16' after I use the gcc command.

Comment: Ok so it wasn't working with %option noyywrap but when I added the int main() and yywrap it started working. I will post the working code and proper way of compiling.

Comment: You need to provide `main`. `%option noyywrap` only means that you don't need to provide `yywrap`. Was that not clear in my answer?

Answer (score -1):

So the proper code for lex is:

```
%{
#include "z5.tab.h"
%}

%%
[\(\)] return(yytext[0]);
. {printf("%c - error!\n",yytext[0]);}
\n ;
%%
int main(void)
{
   yyparse();
   return 0;
}

int yywrap(void)
{
   return 0;
}
void yyerror(char* x)
{
    printf("syntax error");
    exit(1);
}
```

and the proper way to compile it is:

```
flex s5.l 
bison -d z5.y 
gcc lex.yy.c z5.tab.c -L"C:\GnuWin32\lib"
```

Comment: Yywrap should return 1, not 0. 0 means that you have more input even though EOF was reported, because `yyin` has been changed to a different input stream. But you have not done that. Better to use `%option noyywrap` to avoid the need for yywrap.